# Highcharts, visual issue on pie chart border. Any idea how to fix it?

Tags: html, css, svg, highcharts

I'm trying to do a really custom pie chart using Highcharts. So far I've been able to do what I wanted. The only problem is that when I remove the borders of the pie chart, then there's like a little glitch on the border of a slice. See the image here:

http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/7139/piechart.png

Is there a way to fix this?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It is possible to reproduce this chart in the jsfiddle.net?

Comment: here is a jsFiddle from the default Highchart Pie-Chart: http://jsfiddle.net/98jNE/

A small gap is visible on different zoom levels and disappears on others. Could be a rounding Problem.